# Windows 8 Desktop multitouch API

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-8, multi-touch

I'm developing a c# touch application for windows 8, desktop mode, and i'm unable to find the best approach to do it. My question is: Should I use the existent Windows 7 Touch API c# or there is a new multitouch c# API that can be used to develop windows 8 desktops apps?

I know that windows 8 have legacy support for the win7 touch api, just need some insight and feedback if still is the best and only way to do it.

Does anyone had a previous experience with this problem?

Edited: I found this article: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/touch-gestures , basically the UIElement exposes methods that enable touch manipulation. Maybe this is the way to go. Any thoughts?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 8 API has a new API based on WM_POINTER message see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454916(v=vs.85).aspx

Windows 7 API has some drawbacks, see http://the-witness.net/news/2012/10/wm_touch-is-totally-bananas/

Comment: Thanks Maf, but i think that the Pointer API is to be used with c++ code and I can't find a similar API to c#.

Comment: Then WPF 4 Multitouch API is the way to go. Microsoft has just introduced new multitouch API in Windows 8 Metro apps and C++ low level events.

Answer (score 0):

WM_TOUCHxxx messages are not prone to this problem:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ce6d630a-b345-46ac-88ef-773704986d62/touch-responsiveness-issue-how-to-resolve-jagged-nonsmooth-lines?forum=winappswithcsharp

Both the WM_TOUCHxxx and WM_POINTERxxx message will be prone this this problem:

https://web.archive.org/web/20150709083602/https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/903760/wpf-touch-services-are-badly-broken

If your c# desktop application is using WPF, your only viable option is to implement your own TOUCHDEVICE that fixes these underlying issues, since it appears Microsoft has decided WPF touch is no longer important.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what actually are your needs in your app.

If you only want new fast ways to rotate and zoom objects, maybe the [WPF Manipulation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.manipulation?view=netcore-3.1) is all you need.

If, however, you need to handle multiple fingers on your GUI independently, or in a custom way, you simply handle the usual [OnTouchDown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ontouchdown), [OnTouchMove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.uielement.ontouchmove), and other events.

Please note that, however, multi-touch is only available from inside a single window. In other words: you can multi-touch two objects on the same window, but you won't be able to multi-touch two objects that reside on different windows. If you want multi-touch, multi-window funcionality, you need to:

- Use .NET 4.7
- [Change some configuration in your WPF app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/mitigation-pointer-based-touch-and-stylus-support)